# AttributeError: module 'cplex' has no attribute 'Cplex'

Tags: python, attributeerror, cplex

I am trying to optimize a linear programming problem using CPLEX in Python. 
I already installed the IBM ILOG CPLEX Studio, as well as the docplex in Python.

When I run the program I'm having the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'cplex' has no attribute 'Cplex'
```

Useful code:

```
import docplex.mp.model as cpx

import random

import pandas as pd

n = 10
m = 5
set_I = range(1, n+1)
set_J = range(1, m+1)
c = {(i,j): random.normalvariate(0,1) for i in set_I for j in set_J}
a = {(i,j): random.normalvariate(0,5) for i in set_I for j in set_J}
l = {(i,j): random.randint(0,10) for i in set_I for j in set_J}
u = {(i,j): random.randint(10,20) for i in set_I for j in set_J}
b = {j: random.randint(0,30) for j in set_J}


opt_model = cpx.Model(name="MIP Model")

# if x is Binary
x_vars  = {(i,j): opt_model.binary_var(name="x_{0}_{1}".format(i,j)) for i in set_I for j in set_J}


# <= constraints
constraints = {j : opt_model.add_constraint(ct=opt_model.sum(a[i,j] * x_vars[i,j] for i in set_I) <= b[j], ctname="constraint_{0}".format(j)) for j in set_J}

objective = opt_model.sum(x_vars[i,j] * c[i,j] for i in set_I  for j in set_J)

opt_model.minimize(objective)

opt_model.solve()


opt_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(x_vars, orient="index", columns = ["variable_object"])

opt_df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(opt_df.index, names=["column_i", "column_j"])
opt_df.reset_index(inplace=True)

opt_df["solution_value"] = opt_df["variable_object"].apply(lambda item: item.solution_value)

print(opt_df)
```

I extracted this code from: https://medium.com/@m.moarefdoost/optimization-modeling-in-python-pulp-gurobi-and-cplex-7f25acb03d7d

I am a beginner in CPLEX and Python, so I just tried to run this code to verify thatI've installed everything correctly.

Has anyone had the same kind of problem?

Comment: Can you please show your full code? This should work:
`import cplex` and then `cplex.Cplex()`. Does this give the same error?

Comment: @DanielJunglas thanks for your quick reply. I edited my question and I added the code, I hope it helps you to understand my trouble.

Comment: Can you please also add the full backtrace of the error message? I don't see you using the `cplex` package anywhere. Also make sure that your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable is setup correctly and points to the directory containing the CPLEX Python libraries.

Comment: By the way: your code runs without any problem on my machine.

Comment: @DanielJunglas, my setup.py was not correctly installed, but now I rectified that and my code is running correctly.  Thanks a lot to take your time to help me!

Comment: You are welcome. Can you please add an answer and accept it so that the question can be closed?

Comment: @DanielJunglas, instead of answering my question I just edited that showing what I did to solve my problem.

Comment: @campioni The editions of the question are not intended to provide an answer or add SOLVED to the title, instead you must publish an answer, and mark it as correct tomorrow as indicated by the SO guidelines.

Comment: @eyllanesc I posted my own answer now, but I still cannot accept, since it does not passed 48 hours yet. Tomorrow I will do that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error of my code. 
Actually, I've not installed correctly the setup.py before running my code.

After doing that, everything works well!

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem. I made several mistakes when Setting up the Python API of CPLEX.

1. Instead of using the script setup.py located in `yourCplexhome/python/VERSION/PLATFORM`, I used the script setup.py located in `CPLEX_Studio1210/python`.
2. I didn't set the Python path environment variable PYTHONPATH to the value of `yourCplexhome/python/VERSION/PLATFORM`

[Source](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/GettingStarted/topics/set_up/Python_setup.html)